# Simplifying permutations written in cycle notation

Tags: permutations

I was wondering how I could simplify $((1 3 5)(2 3 4 1)(3 2 1))^{−1}$.

I was going to simplify the inner bracket section first then apply the inverse but I am having trouble simplifying it.

I see that $1\to3\to5\to1 $ but also $1\to3\to4\to1$ and$1\to3\to2\to1$. So I am not sure how to simplify it into one expression?

Thank you, if anyone could help that would be great :)

Comment: You should clarify / confirm whether your permutation "multiplication" is from right to left or from left to right as different authors use the same notation to mean different things.  [See for example this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527514/composition-of-permutations-left-to-right-or-right-to-left).

Comment: @JMoravitz good point. I didn't even think of that.

Comment: As for reminders on how permutation multiplication works [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31763/multiplication-in-permutation-groups-written-in-cyclic-notation) has a good explanation (*noting that it follows the convention that permutations are applied from right to left so that $\sigma\cdot \pi = \sigma \circ \pi$, my personal preferred usage of the notation*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}(135) \text{ takes }1 \to 3 \\ (2341)\text{ takes }3 \to 4 \\ (321) \text{ takes }4 \to 4\end{align*}$$

So, (135)(2341)(321) takes $1 \to 4$, so the inverse would take $4 \to 1$.

$$\begin{align*}(135)\text{ takes }2 \to 2 \\ (2341)\text{ takes }2 \to 3 \\
(321)\text{ takes }3 \to 2\end{align*}$$

So, (135)(2341)(321) takes $2 \to 2$, so the inverse would take $2\to 2$.

Etc.

Final result:
$$(135)(2341)(321) = (1435)$$

$$((135)(2341)(321))^{-1} = (1534)$$

Edit: if the author does multiplication right to left:

$$\begin{align*}(321)\text{ takes }1 \to 3 \\ (2341)\text{ takes }3\to 4 \\ (135) \text{ takes }4 \to 4\end{align*}$$

etc.

Final Result:

$$(135)(2341)(321) = (1435)$$

$$((135)(2341)(321))^{-1} = (1534)$$

This problem happens to work out the same if it is left-to-right or right-to-left multiplication (not all problems will work out that way).

Comment: Ok, but wasn't the inverse requested? Hence the result should be (1534)(2).

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze look above where I wrote Edit:, but if it makes you feel better, I can add it again.

Comment: @ InterstellarProbe  Thank you. Now I'm fine with it. You could also multiply the inverses within the outer bracket (of course in reversed order).