# Help with permutation (13)(246)(1524)

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, permutation-cycles

I am trying to compute a permutation: $\alpha = (13)(246)$ and  $\beta = (1524)$.  Find $\alpha\beta$.  I thought that I had a good grasp on these, but I checked it on a site, and if it is correct, I am wrong and I can't figure out how to make sense of their answer.
I got $\alpha\beta$ = (1543)(26)
Their answer = (1352)(46).

Can anyone give me direction on this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: `$\binom{n}{r}$` gives $\binom{n}{r}$.

Comment: Jose Santos:  Thanks for the help

Comment: Andrew Chin: I don't understand

Comment: It is worth pointing out that [sadly some authors choose to apply permutations from right to left while others prefer to apply permutations from left to right](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527514/composition-of-permutations-left-to-right-or-right-to-left).  Confirm which convention is being used by your teacher / textbook.

Comment: Thank you, JMoravitz.  We are working right to left.  I don't understand how or why there would be more than one way to work a problem if it gives different answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those permutations are bijections $S\to S$ where $S=\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$, and $\alpha\beta = \alpha\circ\beta$. Using what we know, we have $(\alpha\circ\beta)(1)=\alpha(5)=5, (\alpha\circ\beta)(2)=\alpha(4)=6, (\alpha\circ\beta)(3)=\alpha(3)=1, (\alpha\circ\beta)(4)=\alpha(1)=3, (\alpha\circ\beta)(5)=\alpha(2)=4, (\alpha\circ\beta)(6)=\alpha(6)=2$. Thus, 1 goes to 5, 5 goes to 4, 4 goes to 3, 3 goes to 1 (giving you (1543)), and 2 goes to 6, 6 goes to 2 (giving (26)).

Comment: Thank you for your input.  That is what I got, too.  But Wolfram has it different and it makes me wonder if that is correct.

Comment: Perhaps they use the composition the other way around.

Comment: Yep, do the same thing with $\beta\circ\alpha$. You will get what Wolfram gives you.

Comment: THANK YOU!  This has worried me for hours.

Comment: You are welcome.